# How to set max task per child in Celery with Django?

Tags: django, celery

I am trying to set some settings for Celery in my Django setup, but wherever I put this:

```
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=1
```

it always allows to start multiple tasks at the same time. I tried putting it in `settings.py` and `proj.settings`. My `celery.py` is as follows:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'proj.settings')

app = Celery('proj', backend='redis://', broker='redis://localhost')


# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no limit by default.

Try

```
from celery import conf
conf.CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1 #max_tasks_per_child
```

Also, you can pass it through the cmd as parameter at starting (depends of ver.):

```
--maxtasksperchild=1
```

or

```
--max-tasks-per-child=1
```

[Source](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-max-tasks-per-child)

Answer (score 3):

The place where it should go is `settings.py`:

```
CELERY_WORKER_CONCURRENCY = 1   # this is the one I was actually looking for
CELERY_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD = 1
```